# Почему || обрезает в некоторых значениях число слева, либо выдает значения значения вида 5,876544358765677786E-8?

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Мне нужно посчитать процент в `Oracle Developer`. Данные потом переносятся в `excel`. В `excel`, если выбрать формат столбца, процент не нужно при делении умножать на `100`, а достаточно просто
`col1/col2`.

Но в этом случае для некоторых столбцов выдает значения вида `5,876544358765677786E-8`,
если пишу в таком виде:
`ROUND((col1/col2*100),8) || '%'`, то в некоторых значениях обрезает `0` до запятой и выводит `,056789543`

Как сделать, чтобы либо выводил значения, которые можно скопировать в `excel` и там применить формат процент, либо добавить знак `%` и чтобы не обрезал значения?

Comment: не надо надеяться на то, что какая-то IDE напечатет число в нужном вам формате.  вместо этого сами в sql-запросе используйте функцию to_char для перевода числа в строку с явным указанием десятичного формата

Comment: пробую to_char вместо round - to_char((col1/col2 *100),'9999.99') || '%' но все равно первые символы обрезает в некоторых значениях

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не обрезало ноль, используйте формат с нулём, а не девяткой

```
select to_char(col1/col2*100, '9990.00')||'%' from dual
```